peerConnection.ontrack never called
This is my code. The HTML is mainly used to receive video streams. Through webrtc-internal, I can see that the video stream is being received and continues to do so, but the peerConnection.ontrack event is never triggered. How can this be resolved?
const signalingServerUrl = "ws://localhost:8899";
const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

let peerConnection;
let signalingSocket = new WebSocket(signalingServerUrl);
let dataChannel;

const configuration = {
    iceServers: [
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' }
    ],
    sdpSemantics: 'unified-plan'
};

signalingSocket.onopen = () => {
    console.log("Connected to signaling server");
};

signalingSocket.onmessage = async (message) => {
    try {
        const data = await message.data.text();  // Convert Blob to text
        const json = JSON.parse(data);

        switch(json.type) {
            case 'SessionDescription':
                await handleSessionDescription(json.payload);
                break;
            case 'IceCandidate':
                await handleCandidate(json.payload);
                break;
            default:
                console.error("Unknown message type:", json.type);
                break;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error parsing message data:", error);
    }
};

signalingSocket.onclose = () => {
    console.log("Disconnected from signaling server");
};

async function handleSessionDescription(sdp) {
    if (!peerConnection) {
        createPeerConnection();
    }

    const sessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(sdp);
    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription);

    if (sessionDescription.type === 'offer') {
        const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

        sendMessage({
            type: 'SessionDescription',
            payload: {
                type: answer.type,
                sdp: answer.sdp
            }
        });
    }
}

async function handleCandidate(candidate) {
    if (peerConnection) {
        const iceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(candidate);
        await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
        console.log('Added ICE candidate:', candidate);
    }
}

function createPeerConnection() {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
    peerConnection.ondatachannel = (event) => {
        dataChannel = event.channel;
        dataChannel.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Data channel is open');
            const message = "Hello from HTML!";
            dataChannel.send(message);
            console.log('Sent message:', message);
        };
        dataChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
            // Assuming the data is sent as a string encoded in UTF-8
            if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
                // Convert ArrayBuffer to string
                const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
                const text = decoder.decode(event.data);
                console.log('Received message:', text);
            } else if (typeof event.data === 'string') {
                // Directly handle string data
                console.log('Received message:', event.data);
            } else {
                console.error('Unknown data type:', event.data);
            }
        };
        dataChannel.onclose = () => {
            console.log('Data channel is closed');
        };
        dataChannel.onerror = (error) => {
            console.error('Data channel error:', error);
        };
    };

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
        if (event.candidate) {
            const candidate = {
                sdp: event.candidate.candidate,
                sdpMid: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                sdpMLineIndex: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                usernameFragment: event.candidate.usernameFragment
            };

            sendMessage({
                type: 'IceCandidate',
                payload: candidate
            });
            console.log('Generated ICE candidate:', event.candidate);
        }
    };


    peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
      
      console.log(1111111111);
      const videoTrack = videoTransceiver.receiver.track;

      const remoteStream = new MediaStream([videoTrack]);

      let totalSize = 0;

      videoTrack.onunmute = () => {
        const processor = new MediaStreamTrackProcessor({ track: videoTrack });
        const reader = processor.readable.getReader();

        const readChunk = ({ done, value }) => {
          if (done) {
            console.log('Stream processing complete');
            return;
          }

          totalSize += value.byteLength;
          console.log(`Current chunk size: ${value.byteLength}, Total size: ${totalSize}`);

          reader.read().then(readChunk);
        };

        reader.read().then(readChunk);
      };
    };


    peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
        console.log('ICE connection state changed to:', peerConnection.iceConnectionState);
        switch (peerConnection.iceConnectionState) {
            case 'new':
                console.log('ICE connection state: new');
                break;
            case 'checking':
                console.log('ICE connection state: checking');
                break;
            case 'connected':
                console.log('ICE connection state: connected');
                break;
            case 'completed':
                console.log('ICE connection state: completed');
                break;
            case 'disconnected':
                console.log('ICE connection state: disconnected');
                break;
            case 'failed':
                console.log('ICE connection state: failed');
                break;
            case 'closed':
                console.log('ICE connection state: closed');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    peerConnection.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
        console.log('Connection state changed to:', peerConnection.connectionState);
        switch (peerConnection.connectionState) {
            case 'new':
                console.log('Connection state: new');
                break;
            case 'connecting':
                console.log('Connection state: connecting');
                break;
            case 'connected':
                console.log('Connection state: connected');
                break;
            case 'disconnected':
                console.log('Connection state: disconnected');
                break;
            case 'failed':
                console.log('Connection state: failed');
                break;
            case 'closed':
                console.log('Connection state: closed');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    peerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = () => {
        console.log('ICE gathering state changed to:', peerConnection.iceGatheringState);
        switch (peerConnection.iceGatheringState) {
            case 'new':
                console.log('ICE gathering state: new');
                break;
            case 'gathering':
                console.log('ICE gathering state: gathering');
                break;
            case 'complete':
                console.log('ICE gathering state: complete');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = () => {
        console.log('Signaling state changed to:', peerConnection.signalingState);
        switch (peerConnection.signalingState) {
            case 'stable':
                console.log('Signaling state: stable');
                break;
            case 'have-local-offer':
                console.log('Signaling state: have-local-offer');
                break;
            case 'have-remote-offer':
                console.log('Signaling state: have-remote-offer');
                break;
            case 'have-local-pranswer':
                console.log('Signaling state: have-local-pranswer');
                break;
            case 'have-remote-pranswer':
                console.log('Signaling state: have-remote-pranswer');
                break;
            case 'closed':
                console.log('Signaling state: closed');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(message);
    const buffer = new TextEncoder().encode(jsonString);  // Convert JSON string to ArrayBuffer
    signalingSocket.send(buffer);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // No need to start local stream or create an offer
});


webrtc-internals capture shown here：
enter image description here
webrtc-internals:
enter image description here
enter image description here
